# ios dropbox, loading thumbnail of image in table view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, dropbox-api

I have picture in my dropbox, which i need to show in Uitable view. I am able to show the picture by name, using metadata filemetadata, and when i click on any of cell i am successfully able to view the image in image view, by using the call to loadthumbnail.
But now, I want to show the thumbnail of image together with, image name, so that user have idea of image before opening it.
So, what is the simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should resize (thumb) the original `UIImage`'s prior to showing the `UITableView` and save them in your app cache folder.

Something like this (out the top of my head)

```
CGSize targetSize = (CGSize){ 100, 80 };
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);

CGRect thumbnailRect = (CGRect){ 0, 0, targetSize.width, targetSize.height };

[sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];    
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// After this you should store the UIImage (NSData) as a file, so you could use it later on.
```

Comment: in dropbox api there is mention of thumbnails, can i use that, if so then how

Comment: ok, got it, I have to use the api call loadthumbnail only by specifying the size small, and then saving the image in image cache, thanks for your time

Comment: @cocoaNoob hey mate can you give me some idea or code for display that thumbnail in cell please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to the Start Menu then look for My Documents and look for a folder named Downloads. This worked for me on a download i could not see.

Good Luck!

Comment: the OP is referring to a functionality related to iOs development, so this is not related to a Windows Environment.